# Set property category for WPF custom control?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, custom-controls

In WinForms, I could add a [Category] attribute to a custom control property to specify which property category should contain the property. How do I do that in WPF? Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have discovered that you don't *have* to include a design-time DLL to add a [Category] attribute to a custom control property. That is one way that it can be done, but in fact, you can use any .NET attribute just as you did in WinForms. For example:

```
/// <summary>
/// The image displayed by the button.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>The image is specified in XAML as an absolute or relative path.</remarks>
[Description("The image displayed by the button."), Category("Common Properties")] 
public ImageSource Image
{
    get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ImageProperty, value); }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide a "metadata assembly," also known as a "design time DLL."  This is an assembly with the same name as your main assembly with .Design appended to it (e.g. MyCompany.MyControls.Design.dll), and containing a class that implements IRegisterMetadata.  The IRegisterMetadata implementation builds a table of attributes for the various components in your main assembly, and adds this to a MetadataStore.

For full info and examples, see blog posts by Jim Nakashima of the Cider team [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/jnak/archive/2007/08/10/adding-design-time-metadata-to-cider-and-blend.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/jnak/archive/2007/08/14/how-are-metadata-assemblies-found.aspx).

For documentation, see [WPF Designer Extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546938.aspx) in MSDN.